# Capturing Value From RS Forms Drop Down

Tags: joomla-4.x, rsform

Using RSForms and Joomla - how can I capture the selected value of a drop down in the php code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the value each field of your Form using the $_Post.

For example where a_field is the field name in your form.

$fred = $_POST['form']['a_field']

There are more hits in the Form Properties Tab under the PHP Script menu item and plenty of examples on the RS Joomla Forum.